# How to Validate an Access Token for OAuth2 + PCKE flow

Tags: api, session, authentication, token, onelogin

According to this document
https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/guides/auth-flow-pkce

Token Endpoint for PCKE flow is **None** (not Basic or POST)

[image]

So, how can I use the validation token API https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/validate-session because it supports `Basic authentication` or `POST` but not for `None (PCKE)` I can't find any information relate to this.

**NOTE:** I have tried to request with Basic authentication and without + client_id, client_secret as a parameter but not working.

response 401 Unauthorized

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "client authentication failed"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using OIDC with PKCE, and I managed to call the https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token/introspection endpoint with a token retrieved via the authorization code flow:

```
$ curl -i -d "token=...&token_type_hint=access_token&client_id=..." https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token/introspection

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Length: 304
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 23:37:42 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: Express
Set-Cookie: ol_oidc_canary_040819=false; path=/; domain=.onelogin.com

{"active":true,"sub":"...","client_id":"...","exp":1558819177,"iat":1556227177,"sid":"...","iss":"https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc","jti":"...","scope":"openid profile email"}
```

Both the `access_token` and `refresh_token` returned from the auth code flow https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code-grant worked, and the `access_token` only returned `{"active":false}` after it expired.

Make sure you are not setting the `Authorization` header, and only set your `client_id` in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Use client_id and code_verify in the POST body. That will authenticate the request on that endpoint.

Comment: I found out that it's not required to pass code_verify in the request body!?

Comment: Hi Jongz. It's Niall. You and I are talking through another channel :)

Comment: LoL earth is round! @niall_atlasidentity